# How to ignore NA when applying relativedelta

Tags: python, relativedelta

I have to add 'N' no.of months in the date column and was trying to use this 
function to help me to do so.

```
order_emis_full['calc_due_date']=order_emis_full['agreement_date'].apply(lambda  x: x + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1))
```

I keep getting the error

```
 IllegalMonthError: bad month number nan; must be 1-12
```

Comment: Please show your input data frame.

Comment: You either have a string or `NaN` so do `order_emis_full['calc_due_date'].fillna(0, inplace=True)` or `order_emis_full['calc_due_date'].replace('nan',0, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Without much context, this is something I would do to catch the error and supply a backup number

```
from calendar import IllegalMonthError

try:
   order_emis_full['calc_due_date']=order_emis_full['agreement_date'].apply(lambda  x: x + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1))

except IllegalMonthError:
   'Your error catching code'
```

You could also add the try except statement in your pandas apply function so that you can control what value to be backfilled whenever there is `IllegalMonthError` exception